# connect to database data in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I've see the calendar code on arshaw/fullcalendar. And I've changed a little code, but I still don't know how to connect javascript into database..

Here's the original code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},

selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
var title = prompt('Event Title:');
if (title) {
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
{
title: title,
start: start,
end: end,
allDay: allDay
},
true // make the event "stick"
);
}
calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
editable: true,

});

});
```

And this I changed a bit

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {

newwindow=window.open('2.php','name','height=400,width=300');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
if (title) {
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
{
title: title,
start: start,
end: end,
allDay: allDay
},
true // make the event "stick"
);
}
calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
editable: true,
});

});
```

Where can I put the connection script ?

Need advise..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot establish a connection directly from javascript to use in full calendar

You have to do this

1. Create a Servlet/Action Class/ C# Class (whatever we based **Controller** class);
2. Connect to database from the Controller
3. Write the response data as a JSON String
4. IN the full calendar, add this attribute

   events: "servletURL",

When the calendar loads, the `events` attribute will call the `servletURL`, using ajax and retrieve the response text to display it in the Calendar

Comment: what kind of content the servlet/action class ? Is just a connection or what ? And this class is made from PHP or other language ?